# Proofs of the Weitzenbock inequality: $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 4 \sqrt{3}\cdot(\text{area of }\triangle ABC)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality, contest-math

I'm collecting proofs for [Weitzenbock's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weitzenb%C3%B6ck%27s_inequality), once featured as a question in IMO 1961. I made three proofs for this. See these proofs below. (Whoever has a more cool proof, please share.)

> **Weitzenbock's inequality.** Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be the sides of the triangle, and let $A$ be its area. Then:
>
> $$a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\;\geq\;4\sqrt{3}\;A$$

---

**Proof 1**

Let $R$ the circunradius. Suppose, by contradiction, that:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}<\frac{3}{R\sqrt{3}} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Using that:
\begin{equation}
a+b+c\leq 3R\sqrt{3} \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Multiplying (1) e (2):
$$(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)<9$$
What is absurd, this can be seen using the inequality that relates the arithmetic mean to the harmonic mean, or by the inequality of Cauchy-Schwarz. From where we conclude:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\geq\frac{3}{R\sqrt{3}}
\end{equation}
Using $\displaystyle A=\frac{abc}{4R}$, we get:
$$ab+ac+bc\geq \frac{\sqrt{3}abc}{R}$$
$$ab+ac+bc\geq 4A\sqrt{3}$$
This result follows using that $\displaystyle a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\geq ab+bc+ac$

---

**Proof 2**

By Heron we get:

\begin{equation*}
    a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq 4\sqrt{3} \sqrt{S(S-a)(S-b)(S-c)}
\end{equation*}

Multiplying both sides of the inequality above by $\displaystyle \sqrt{\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2abc}\right)^2}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{S}{abc}\right)^2}$, :
\begin{equation*}
    \left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2abc}\right) \geq 4\sqrt{3} \sqrt{\frac{S(S-a)}{bc}\frac{S(S-b)}{ac}\frac{S(S-c)}{ab}}
\end{equation*}
By the law of cosine and law of sine we have:

\begin{equation*}
    \left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2abc}\right) \geq 4\sqrt{3} \cos\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\frac{\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\gamma}{2}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \left(\frac{a^2}{bc}+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{a}{c}\right)+ \left(\frac{b^2}{ac}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{b}{c}\right)+ \left(\frac{c^2}{ab}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{c}{b}\right) \geq 8\sqrt{3} \cos\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\frac{\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\gamma}{2}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
      \left(\frac{sen^2\alpha}{sen\beta sen\gamma}+\frac{sen\alpha}{sen\beta}+\frac{sen\alpha}{sen\gamma}\right)+\left(\frac{sen^2\beta}{sen\alpha sen\gamma}+\frac{sen\beta}{sen\alpha}+\frac{sen\beta}{sen\gamma}\right)+\left(\frac{sen^2\gamma}{sen\alpha sen\beta}+\frac{sen\gamma}{sen\alpha}+\frac{sen\gamma}{sen\beta}\right)  \geq 8\sqrt{3} \cos\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\frac{\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\gamma}{2}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
      (sen\alpha+sen\beta+sen\gamma)\left(\frac{sen\alpha}{sen\beta sen\gamma}+\frac{sen\beta}{sen\alpha sen\gamma}+\frac{sen\gamma}{sen\alpha sen\beta}\right) \geq 8\sqrt{3} \cos\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\frac{\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\gamma}{2}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
      \cot\alpha+\cot\beta+\cot\gamma\geq \sqrt{3}
 \end{equation*}
And this inequality follows from the Jensen inequality.

---

**Proof 3**

Let $\displaystyle R$ the circunradius, $\displaystyle \alpha, \beta, \gamma$ the opposite acute angles to the sides of $\displaystyle a, b, c$, so:

$\\ \\ \displaystyle a^2+b^2-c^2=\frac{4Rabc(a^2+b^2-c^2)}{4Rabc}=\frac{4AR(a^2+b^2-c^2)}{abc}=4A\times\frac{2R}{c}\times\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}=4Acot\gamma=4A\sqrt{cot^2\gamma}=4A\sqrt{csc^2\gamma-1}=4A\sqrt{\frac{4R^2}{c^2}-1}=4A\sqrt{\frac{4a^2b^2R^2}{a^2b^2c^2}-1}=4A\sqrt{\frac{a^2b^2}{4\left(\frac{abc}{4R}\right)^2}-1}=4A\sqrt{\frac{a^2b^2}{4A^2}-1}=2\sqrt{4A^2\left(\frac{a^2b^2}{4A^2}-1\right)}=2\sqrt{a^2b^2-4A^2}\Rightarrow a^2+b^2-c^2=2\sqrt{a^2b^2-4A^2}\\ \\$

By symmetry, we get:

\begin{equation*}
 2\sqrt{a^2b^2-4A^2}=a^2+b^2-c^2
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
 2\sqrt{a^2c^2-4A^2}=a^2+c^2-b^2
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
2\sqrt{b^2c^2-4A^2}=b^2+c^2-a^2
\end{equation*}

Multiplying these equalities two by two we will have:

\begin{equation*}
 4\sqrt{a^2b^2-4A^2}\sqrt{b^2c^2-4A^2}=(a^2+b^2-c^2)(b^2+c^2-a^2)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
 4\sqrt{a^2c^2-4A^2}\sqrt{b^2c^2-4A^2}=(a^2+c^2-b^2)(b^2+c^2-a^2)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
4\sqrt{a^2b^2-4A^2}\sqrt{a^2c^2-4A^2}=(a^2+c^2-b^2)(a^2+b^2-c^2)
\end{equation*}

We know that $\displaystyle m+n\geq 2\sqrt{mn}$, it folows that:

\begin{equation*}
 2(a^2b^2-4A^2+b^2c^2-4A^2)\geq (a^2+b^2-c^2)(b^2+c^2-a^2)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
 2(a^2c^2-4A^2+b^2c^2-4A^2)\geq(a^2+c^2-b^2)(b^2+c^2-a^2)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
2(a^2b^2-4A^2+a^2c^2-4A^2)\geq(a^2+c^2-b^2)(a^2+b^2-c^2)
\end{equation*}

Adding all the above inequalities we will have:
\begin{equation*}
4a^2b^2+4b^2c^2+4a^2c^2-16\times 3 A^2\geq (a^2+b^2-c^2)(b^2+c^2-a^2)+(a^2+c^2-b^2)(b^2+c^2-a^2)+(a^2+c^2-b^2)(b^2+c^2-a^2)
\end{equation*}

Let $ b^2+c^2-a^2=x,y=a^2+c^2-b^2,z=a^2+b^2-c^2$.Observe that

$$ 2a^2=(a^2+c^2-b^2)+(a^2+b^2-c^2)=y+z$$

$$ 2b^2=(a^2+b^2-c^2)+(b^2+c^2-a^2)=x+z$$

$$ 2c^2=(a^2+c^2-b^2)+(b^2+c^2-a^2)=x+y$$

We get:

$$ 4a^2b^2=(y+z)(x+z)$$

$$ 4a^2c^2=(y+z)(x+y)$$

$$ 4b^2c^2=(x+z)(x+y)$$

Replacing in the inequality above, we have:

\begin{equation*}
(x+z)(x+y)+(y+z)(x+y)+(y+z)(x+z)-16\times 3 A^2\geq xy+xz+yz
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2xz+2yz-16\times 3 A^2\geq 0
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
(x+y+z)^2-16\times 3 A^2\geq 0
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
x+y+z\geq 4\sqrt{3}A
\end{equation*}

Done

Comment: 1961 different proofs of the Weitzenbock inequality? Wow, that's a lot of proofs. I have a book with 344 different proofs of the Pythagorean theorem, but that's nothing compared to this.

Comment: Ops That's not what I meant.

Comment: You can see some methods [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weitzenb%C3%B6ck's_inequality).

Comment: Maybe replace all "sen" by $\sin$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about a proof (almost) without words?

[image]

Let us consider a triangle $ABC$ and its Fermat-Torricelli-Steiner point, such that $\widehat{CFA}=\widehat{AFC}=\widehat{CFB}=120^\circ$. It is well-known that $F$ lies on each line joining a vertex of $ABC$ with the free vertex of the equilateral triangle built on the opposite side. By replicating the (colored) triangles $AFC,CFB,BFA$ four times we reach the configuration depicted above. Due to the triangular holes
$$ [ABV_C]+[ACV_B]+[BCV_A]\geq 3[ABC] $$
that is equivalent to the claim.

---

There also is an efficient variational approach. If $ABC$ is a triangle in the plane with $AB=c,AC=b$, the locus of points $P$ such that $PB^2+PC^2=b^2+c^2$ is a circle through $A$ centered at the midpoint of $BC$. It follows that by moving the vertex $A$ along such circle, till meeting the perpendicular bisector of $BC$, the area of $ABC$ increases but $AB^2+BC^2+AC^2$ stays the same. It follows that for a fixed $a^2+b^2+c^2$, the maximum area is achieved only by the equilateral triangle, and $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 4\sqrt{3}\Delta$ follows.

---

Yet another way is to exploit the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. We have
$$ (1+1+1)(a^4+b^4+c^4)\geq (a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 $$
hence:
$$ 4\Delta = \sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-2(a^4+b^4+c^4)} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(a^2+b^2+c^2). $$

---

**Update**. Yet another way is to prove a stronger inequality, namely
$$ ab+ac+bc \geq 4\Delta\sqrt{3} $$
which follows from $ab=\frac{2\Delta}{\sin C}$ and the convexity of $\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$ over $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: Very good!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @IsraelMeirelesChrisostomo: there are quite a few exclamation marks, thank you! :D

Comment: Wow, this is crisp and pretty!

Answer (score 6):

There are some proofs at https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h14388 and a generalization at https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2958 . Let me actually reproduce my post in the latter thread in full here (with minor modifications -- neither my exposition nor my LaTeX were particularly good back in 2005), which proves several generalizations:

## 1. The Pedoe and Bottema inequalities

> **Theorem 1.** Let $ABC$ be a triangle with sidelengths $a = BC$, $b = CA$, $c = AB$ and area $S$. Let $XYZ$ be a triangle with sidelengths $x = YZ$, $y = ZX$, $z = XY$ and area $T$.
>
> **(a) (Pedoe inequality)** Then, we have the inequality
>   \begin{align}
> a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)\geq 16ST ,
> \end{align}
>   with equality if and only if the triangles $ABC$ and $XYZ$ are similar.
>
> **(b) (Bottema inequality)** If $P$ is an arbitrary point in the plane of triangle $ABC$, then we have the inequality
>
> \begin{align}
> & x\cdot AP+y\cdot BP+z\cdot CP \\
> & \geq \sqrt{\dfrac{a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)}{2}+8ST} .
> \end{align}
>
> **(c) (Equivalent version of (a))** Let $A = \measuredangle CAB$, $B = \measuredangle ABC$, $C = \measuredangle BCA$ be the angles of triangle $ABC$. Let $X = \measuredangle ZXY$, $Y = \measuredangle XYZ$, $Z = \measuredangle YZX$ be the angles of triangle $XYZ$. Then,
>   \begin{align}
> \cot A\cot Y+\cot A\cot Z+\cot B\cot Z+\cot B\cot X+\cot C\cot X+\cot C\cot Y \geq 2 .
> \end{align}
>   This inequality becomes an equality if and only if the triangles $ABC$ and $XYZ$ are similar.

*Proof of Theorem 1.*

**(a)** First note that the inequality which we must prove,
\begin{align}
a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)\geq 16ST ,
\end{align}
is homogeneous in the sidelengths $x$, $y$, $z$ of the triangle $XYZ$ (in fact, these sidelengths occur in the power $2$ on the left hand side, and on the right hand side they occur in the power $2$ as well, since the area of a triangle depends quadratically on its sidelengths). Hence, this inequality is invariant under any similitude transformation applied to triangle $XYZ$; in other words, we can move, reflect, rotate and stretch the triangle $XYZ$ as we wish, and the inequality remains equivalent. But, of course, by applying similitude transformations to triangle $XYZ$, we can always achieve a situation when $Y = B$ and $Z = C$ and the point $X$ lies in the same halfplane with respect to the line $BC$ as the point $A$. Hence, in order to prove Theorem 1 **(a)** for *every* two triangles $ABC$ and $XYZ$, it is enough to prove it for two triangles $ABC$ and $XYZ$ in this special situation.

So, let us WLOG assume that the triangles $ABC$ and $XYZ$ are in this special situation, i. e. that we have $Y = B$ and $Z = C$ and the point $X$ lies in the same halfplane with respect to the line $BC$ as the point $A$. We have to prove the inequality $a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)\geq 16ST$.

By the cosine law in triangle $ABX$, we have

$AX^2=AB^2+XB^2-2\cdot AB\cdot XB\cdot\cos\measuredangle ABX$.

Let's figure out what this equation means. At first, $AB = c$. Then, since $B = Y$, we have $XB = XY = z$. Finally, we have either $\measuredangle ABX = \measuredangle ABC - \measuredangle XBC$ or $\measuredangle ABX = \measuredangle XBC - \measuredangle ABC$ (depending on the arrangement of the points), but in both cases $\cos \measuredangle ABX = \cos \left(\measuredangle ABC - \measuredangle XBC\right)$. Since $B = Y$ and $C = Z$, we can rewrite the angle $\measuredangle XBC$ as $\measuredangle XYZ$. Thus,

$\cos\measuredangle ABX=\cos\left(\measuredangle ABC-\measuredangle XYZ\right)=\cos\measuredangle ABC\cos\measuredangle XYZ+\sin\measuredangle ABC\sin\measuredangle XYZ$.

By the cosine law in triangles $ABC$ and $XYZ$, we have

$\cos\measuredangle ABC=\dfrac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{2ca}$ and
$\cos\measuredangle XYZ=\dfrac{z^2+x^2-y^2}{2zx}$.

Also, by a well-known formula, the area $S$ of triangle $ABC$ equals $S=\dfrac12\cdot ca\sin\measuredangle ABC$; thus, $\sin\measuredangle ABC=\dfrac{2S}{ca}$. Similarly, $\sin\measuredangle XYZ=\dfrac{2T}{zx}$.

Hence,

$\cos\measuredangle ABX=\cos\measuredangle ABC\cos\measuredangle XYZ+\sin\measuredangle ABC\sin\measuredangle XYZ$
$=\dfrac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{2ca}\cdot\dfrac{z^2+x^2-y^2}{2zx}+\dfrac{2S}{ca}\cdot\dfrac{2T}{zx}$.

Together with $AB = c$ and $XB = z$, this makes the equality

$AX^2=AB^2+XB^2-2\cdot AB\cdot XB\cdot\cos\measuredangle ABX$

transform into

$AX^2=c^2+z^2-2\cdot c\cdot z\cdot\left(\dfrac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{2ca}\cdot\dfrac{z^2+x^2-y^2}{2zx}+\dfrac{2S}{ca}\cdot\dfrac{2T}{zx}\right)$.

This immediately simplifies to

$AX^2=c^2+z^2-2\left(\dfrac{\left(c^2+a^2-b^2\right)\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)}{4ax}+\dfrac{4ST}{ax}\right)$.

After some algebra, this becomes

$AX^2=\dfrac{\left(a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)-2Q\right)-16ST}{2ax}$,

where $Q = \left(x-a\right)\left(c^2x-z^2a\right)$.

Since $Y = B$ and $Z = C$, we have $YZ = BC$, or, in other words, $x = a$. Thus, $x - a = 0$, so that $Q = 0$. Hence, the above formula for $AX^2$ simplifies to

$AX^2=\dfrac{\left(a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)\right)-16ST}{2ax}$.

Since (obviously) $AX^2\geq 0$, we thus have

$\left(a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)\right)-16ST\geq 0$,

and thus $a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)\geq 16ST$. So the inequality of Theorem 1 **(a)** is proven. Equality holds if and only if equality holds in the inequality $AX^2\geq 0$; but this is clearly the case if and only if the points $A$ and $X$ coincide, i. e. if the triangles $ABC$ and $XYZ$ are congruent. Now, of course, since the triangle $XYZ$ we are dealing with is not the initial triangle $XYZ$, but just its image under a similitude transformation, the general equality condition is that the triangles $ABC$ and $XYZ$ are similar (not necessarily being congruent). So Theorem 1 **(a)** is proven.

**(b)** In our proof of Theorem 1 **(a)**, we WLOG assumed that $Y = B$ and $Z = C$ and the point $X$ lies in the same halfplane with respect to the line $BC$ as the point $A$. This time we will assume the same situation, but with a little modification: The point $X$ should lie not in the same halfplane with respect to the line $BC$ as the point $A$, but exactly in the other halfplane. In other words, we have $Y = B$ and $Z = C$ and the points $A$ and $X$ lie in different halfplanes with respect to the line $BC$. Then, by a calculation similar to the one we did in the proof of Theorem 1 **(a)**, we find

$AX^2=\dfrac{\left(a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)\right)+16ST}{2ax}$

(note the $+$ sign instead of the $-$). Since $x = a$, we have $ax=a^2$, and thus we can rewrite this as

$AX^2=\dfrac{\left(a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)\right)+16ST}{2a^2}$.

Hence,

$a^2\cdot AX^2=\dfrac{\left(a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)\right)+16ST}{2}$
${=\dfrac{a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)}{2}+8ST}$.

Taking the square root of this, we get

$a\cdot AX=\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)}{2}+8ST}$.

Hence, the inequality which is to be proven,

$x\cdot AP+y\cdot BP+z\cdot CP\geq \sqrt{\dfrac{a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)}{2}+8ST}$,

is equivalent to $x\cdot AP+y\cdot BP+z\cdot CP\geq a\cdot AX$.

So we have to prove $x\cdot AP+y\cdot BP+z\cdot CP\geq a\cdot AX$.

Well, first, by the [Ptolemy inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy's_inequality) for the quadrilateral $PBXC$, we have $CX\cdot BP+XB\cdot CP\geq BC\cdot PX$. Since $B = Y$ and $C = Z$, we have $CX = ZX = y$, $XB = XY = z$ and $BC = YZ = x$, and therefore this inequality rewrites as $y\cdot BP+z\cdot CP\geq x\cdot PX$. Also, by the triangle inequality in the triangle $APX$, we have $AP+PX\geq AX$. Thus,

$x\cdot AP+y\cdot BP+z\cdot CP=x\cdot AP+\left(y\cdot BP+z\cdot CP\right)\geq x\cdot AP+x\cdot PX$
$=x\cdot\left(AP+PX\right)\geq x\cdot AX=a\cdot AX$,

where we have used $x = a$ in the last step. This proves Theorem 1 **(b)**.

**(c)** By the Cosine Law in triangle $ABC$, we have $\cos A=\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$. On the other hand, by a well-known formula for the area of a triangle, the area $S$ of triangle $ABC$ equals $S=\dfrac12bc\sin A$. Thus, $\sin A=\dfrac{2S}{bc}$. Hence,

$\cot A=\cos A / \sin A=\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc} / \dfrac{2S}{bc}=\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{4S}$.

Similarly, $\cot B=\dfrac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{4S}$. Thus, $\cot A+\cot B=\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{4S}+\dfrac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{4S}=\dfrac{2c^2}{4S}=\dfrac{c^2}{2S}$.

Similarly to how we proved $\cot A=\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{4S}$, we can find that $\cot Z=\dfrac{x^2+y^2-z^2}{4T}$. Thus,

$\cot A\cot Z+\cot B\cot Z=\left(\cot A+\cot B\right)\cdot\cot Z=\dfrac{c^2}{2S}\cdot\dfrac{x^2+y^2-z^2}{4T}$
$=\dfrac{c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)}{8ST}$.

Similarly,

$\cot B\cot X+\cot C\cot X=\dfrac{a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)}{8ST}$ and
$\cot C\cot Y+\cot A\cot Y=\dfrac{b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)}{8ST}$.

Thus,

$\cot A\cot Y+\cot A\cot Z+\cot B\cot Z+\cot B\cot X+\cot C\cot X+\cot C\cot Y$
$=\left(\cot B\cot X+\cot C\cot X\right)+\left(\cot C\cot Y+\cot A\cot Y\right)+\left(\cot A\cot Z+\cot B\cot Z\right)$
$=\dfrac{a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)}{8ST}+\dfrac{b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)}{8ST}+\dfrac{c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)}{8ST}$
$=\dfrac{a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)}{8ST}$.

But after Theorem 1 **(a)**, we have $a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)\geq 16ST$, with equality if and only if the triangles $ABC$ and $XYZ$ are similar. Hence,

$\cot A\cot Y+\cot A\cot Z+\cot B\cot Z+\cot B\cot X+\cot C\cot X+\cot C\cot Y$
$\geq\dfrac{16ST}{8ST}=2$,

with equality if and only if the triangles $ABC$ and $XYZ$ are similar. And Theorem 1 **(c)** is proven. $\blacksquare$

## 2. Some applications of Pedoe

Note that Theorem 1 **(a)** yields the following geometric inequality:

> **Corollary 2.** Let $ABC$ be a triangle with sidelengths $a = BC$, $b = CA$, $c = AB$ and area $S$. Let $u$, $v$, $w$ be three reals such that the numbers $v + w$, $w + u$, $u + v$ and $vw + wu + uv$ are all nonnegative. [Of course, these conditions are fulfilled if the reals $u$, $v$, $w$ themselves are nonnegative, but also in some other cases.] Then, $ua^2+vb^2+wc^2\geq 4\sqrt{vw+wu+uv}\cdot S$.

Before proving the Corollary, we show two useful facts:

> **Corollary 3 (a well-known formula)**. Let $XYZ$ be a triangle. Let $X = \measuredangle ZXY$, $Y = \measuredangle XYZ$, $Z = \measuredangle YZX$ be the angles of this triangle. Then,
>   \begin{align}
> \cot Y\cdot\cot Z+\cot Z\cdot\cot X+\cot X\cdot\cot Y=1 .
> \end{align}

*Proof of Corollary 3.* Theorem 1 **(c)** (applied to $XYZ$, $x$, $y$ and $z$ instead of $ABC$, $a$, $b$ and $c$) shows that $\cot X\cot Y+\cot X\cot Z+\cot Y\cot Z+\cot Y\cot X+\cot Z\cot X+\cot Z\cot Y \geq 2$, and that this inequality becomes an equality if and only if the triangles $XYZ$ and $XYZ$ are similar. Thus, of course, this inequality becomes an equality (since the triangles $XYZ$ and $XYZ$ are similar). Hence, $\cot X\cot Y+\cot X\cot Z+\cot Y\cot Z+\cot Y\cot X+\cot Z\cot X+\cot Z\cot Y = 2$. Therefore,

$2 = \cot X\cot Y+\cot X\cot Z+\cot Y\cot Z+\cot Y\cot X+\cot Z\cot X+\cot Z\cot Y$
$= 2 \left(\cot Y\cdot\cot Z+\cot Z\cdot\cot X+\cot X\cdot\cot Y\right)$.

Dividing both sides of this equality by $2$, we obtain $1 = \cot Y\cdot\cot Z+\cot Z\cdot\cot X+\cot X\cdot\cot Y$. This proves Corollary 3. $\blacksquare$

> **Theorem 4 (Conway substitution theorem).** Let $u$, $v$, $w$ be three reals such that the numbers $v + w$, $w + u$, $u + v$ and $vw + wu + uv$ are all nonnegative. [Of course, these conditions are fulfilled if the reals $u$, $v$, $w$ themselves are nonnegative, but also in some other cases.] Then, there exists a triangle $XYZ$ with sidelengths
>   \begin{align}
> x=YZ=\sqrt{v+w}, \qquad y=ZX=\sqrt{w+u}, \qquad z=XY=\sqrt{u+v}.
> \end{align}
>   This triangle satisfies
>   \begin{align}
> y^2+z^2-x^2=2u, \qquad z^2+x^2-y^2=2v, \qquad x^2+y^2-z^2=2w.
> \end{align}
>   The area $T$ of this triangle equals
>   \begin{align}
> T=\dfrac12\sqrt{vw+wu+uv} .
> \end{align}
>   If $X = \measuredangle ZXY$, $Y = \measuredangle XYZ$, $Z = \measuredangle YZX$ are the angles of this triangle, then $\cot X=\dfrac{u}{2T}$, $\cot Y=\dfrac{v}{2T}$ and $\cot Z=\dfrac{w}{2T}$.

*Proof of Theorem 4.* Since the numbers $v + w$, $w + u$, $u + v$ are nonnegative, their square roots $\sqrt{v+w}$, $\sqrt{w+u}$, $\sqrt{u+v}$ exist, and, of course, are nonnegative as well. Now, we have $\sqrt{w+u}+\sqrt{u+v}\geq\sqrt{v+w}$, since

$\sqrt{w+u}+\sqrt{u+v}\geq\sqrt{v+w}\ \ \ \ \ \Longleftarrow\ \ \ \ \ \left(\sqrt{w+u}+\sqrt{u+v}\right)^2\geq v+w$

$\Longleftarrow\ \ \ \ \ \left(w+u\right)+\left(u+v\right)+2\sqrt{\left(w+u\right)\left(u+v\right)}\geq v+w$

$\Longleftarrow\ \ \ \ \ 2\sqrt{\left(w+u\right)\left(u+v\right)}\geq -2u$           [this is not trivial, since $u$ needs not be $\geq 0$!]

$\Longleftarrow\ \ \ \ \ \sqrt{\left(w+u\right)\left(u+v\right)}\geq-u\ \ \ \ \ \Longleftarrow\ \ \ \ \ \left(w+u\right)\left(u+v\right)\geq\left(-u\right)^2$

$\Longleftarrow\ \ \ \ \ u^2+\left(vw+wu+uv\right)\geq u^2\ \ \ \ \ \Longleftarrow\ \ \ \ \ vw+wu+uv\geq 0$.

Similarly, $\sqrt{u+v}+\sqrt{v+w}\geq\sqrt{w+u}$ and $\sqrt{v+w}+\sqrt{w+u}\geq\sqrt{u+v}$. Thus, there exists a triangle $XYZ$ with sidelengths $x=YZ=\sqrt{v+w}$, $y=ZX=\sqrt{w+u}$, $z=XY=\sqrt{u+v}$. Denote by $X = \measuredangle ZXY$, $Y = \measuredangle XYZ$, $Z = \measuredangle YZX$ the angles of this triangle. We have

$y^2+z^2-x^2=\left(\sqrt{w+u}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{u+v}\right)^2-\left(\sqrt{v+w}\right)^2$
$=\left(w+u\right)+\left(u+v\right)-\left(v+w\right)=2u$

and similarly $z^2+x^2-y^2=2v$ and $x^2+y^2-z^2=2w$. Now, denoting the area of triangle $XYZ$ by $T$, we note that, as shown during the proof of Theorem 1 **(c)**, we have $\cot Z=\dfrac{x^2+y^2-z^2}{4T}$, so that $\cot Z=\dfrac{2w}{4T}=\dfrac{w}{2T}$, and similarly $\cot X=\dfrac{u}{2T}$ and $\cot Y=\dfrac{v}{2T}$.

Corollary 3 yields $\cot Y\cdot\cot Z+\cot Z\cdot\cot X+\cot X\cdot\cot Y=1$. Using the relations $\cot Z=\dfrac{w}{2T}$, $\cot X=\dfrac{u}{2T}$ and $\cot Y=\dfrac{v}{2T}$, this equality becomes $\dfrac{v}{2T}\cdot\dfrac{w}{2T}+\dfrac{w}{2T}\cdot\dfrac{u}{2T}+\dfrac{u}{2T}\cdot\dfrac{v}{2T}=1$. Hence, $vw+wu+uv=4T^2$, and thus $T=\dfrac12\sqrt{4T^2}=\dfrac12\sqrt{vw+wu+uv}$. This completes the proof of Theorem 4. $\blacksquare$

*Proof of Corollary 2.* Construct a triangle $XYZ$ for our values of $u$, $v$, $w$ according to Theorem 4. Then, applying Theorem 1 **(a)** to the triangles $ABC$ and $XYZ$, we get

$a^2\left(y^2+z^2-x^2\right)+b^2\left(z^2+x^2-y^2\right)+c^2\left(x^2+y^2-z^2\right)\geq 16ST$.

Using the formulas given in Theorem 4, we can rewrite this as

$a^2\cdot 2u+b^2\cdot 2v+c^2\cdot 2w\geq 16S\cdot\dfrac12\sqrt{vw+wu+uv}$.

This simplifies to $ua^2+vb^2+wc^2\geq 4\sqrt{vw+wu+uv}\cdot S$. This proves Corollary 2. $\blacksquare$

> **Corollary 5 (Weitzenböck inequality)**. Let $ABC$ be a triangle with sidelengths $a = BC$, $b = CA$, $c = AB$ and area $S$. Then, $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq 4\sqrt{3} S$.

*Proof of Corollary 5.* Corollary 5 follows from Corollary 2 (applied to $u=1$, $v=1$ and $w=1$). $\blacksquare$

## 3. Another application of Pedoe

We can translate Corollary 2 even further to obtain a purely algebraic inequality (proposed in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h122316p696333 ):

> **Corollary 6.** Let $x$, $y$, $z$ be three nonnegative reals. Let $u$, $v$, $w$ be three reals such that the numbers $v + w$, $w + u$, $u + v$ and $vw + wu + uv$ are all nonnegative. Then,
>   \begin{align}
> u\left(y+z\right)^2 + v\left(z+x\right)^2 + w\left(x+y\right)^2
> \geq 4 \sqrt{\left(vw+wu+uv\right) xyz\left(x+y+z\right)} .
> \end{align}

*Proof of Corollary 6.* We have $\left(y+z\right) + \left(z+x\right) = x+y + \underbrace{2z}_{\geq 0} \geq x+y$ and similarly $\left(z+x\right) + \left(x+y\right) \geq y+z$ and $\left(x+y\right) + \left(y+z\right) \geq z+x$. Hence, the nonnegative reals $y+z$, $z+x$ and $x+y$ are the sidelengths of a triangle. In other words, there exists a triangle $ABC$ with sidelengths $BC = y+z$, $CA = z+x$ and $AB = x+y$. Consider this triangle. Let $S$ be the area of this triangle. Let $a = BC$, $b = CA$ and $c = AB$ denote the sidelengths of this triangle (so that $a = BC = y+z$ etc.), and let $s = \dfrac12\left(a+b+c\right)$ be its semiperimeter.
Then, Heron's formula for the area $S$ of triangle $ABC$ yields
\begin{align}
S = \sqrt{s\left(s-a\right)\left(s-b\right)\left(s-c\right)} .
\end{align}
But we have $a = BC = y+z$ and $b = CA = z+x$ and $c = AB = x+y$. Adding these three equalities together, we obtain $a+b+c = \left(y+z\right)+\left(z+x\right)+\left(x+y\right) = 2\left(x+y+z\right)$, so that $\dfrac12\left(a+b+c\right) = x+y+z$. Hence, $s = \dfrac12\left(a+b+c\right) = x+y+z$. Subtracting the equality $a = y+z$ from this equality, we find $s-a = \left(x+y+z\right)-\left(y+z\right) = x$. Similarly, $s-b = y$ and $s-c = z$.

Now,
\begin{align}
S = \sqrt{s\left(s-a\right)\left(s-b\right)\left(s-c\right)}
= \sqrt{\left(x+y+z\right)xyz}
\end{align}
(since $s = x+y+z$ and $s-a = x$ and $s-b = y$ and $s-c = z$).
But Corollary 2 yields
\begin{align}
ua^2+vb^2+wc^2\geq 4\sqrt{vw+wu+uv}\cdot S .
\end{align}
In view of $a = y+z$ and $b = z+x$ and $c = x+y$ and $S = \sqrt{\left(x+y+z\right)xyz}$,
we obtain
\begin{align}
&u\left(y+z\right)^2 + v\left(z+x\right)^2 + w\left(x+y\right)^2
\\
&\geq 4\sqrt{vw+wu+uv}\cdot \sqrt{\left(x+y+z\right)xyz} \\
&= 4 \sqrt{\left(vw+wu+uv\right) \left(x+y+z\right) xyz} \\
&= 4 \sqrt{\left(vw+wu+uv\right) xyz\left(x+y+z\right)} .
\end{align}
This proves Corollary 6. $\blacksquare$

[*Postscriptum:* I have been atrocious with attribution and citation back in 2005. I am not sure where the ideas in the above proofs come from; I might have been just the scribe. Theorem 1 **(a)** was [discovered in 1943 by Daniel Pedoe and much earlier (without the equality case) by Neuberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedoe's_inequality). It also appears as 10.8 in [O. Bottema, R. Z. Djordjevic, R. R. Janic, D. S. Mitrinovic, P. M. Vasic, *Geometric Inequalities*, Wolters-Noordhoff 1969](http://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Geometric%20Inequalities%20-%20Bottema,%20et.%20al.%20(1968).pdf). Theorem 1 **(b)** appears as 12.56 in the same book and is credited to [O. Bottema, *Hoofdstukken uit de elementaire meetkunde*, Den Haag 1944](http://www.epsilon-uitgaven.nl/E9.php) (I don't have this book, but interestingly it is not out of print). I might have picked up the Conway substitution from posts by John Conway on the Hyacinthos newsgroup long ago.]

Comment: Uow thank's @darij grinberg!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

I think that this answer hasn't been posted yet, so here it goes.

In virtue of the Law of Cosines and the fact that $2A=bc·\sin\alpha$

> $$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 4\sqrt3 A\iff b^2+c^2-2bc·\cos\alpha+b^2+c^2\geq 4·\sqrt3·\frac{bc·\sin\alpha}{2}$$ $$\iff b^2+c^2\geq bc(\sqrt3 \sin\alpha+\cos\alpha)$$

Now observe that for $f(\alpha)=\sqrt3 \sin\alpha+\cos\alpha$ for $\alpha\in(0, \pi)$ you have $$f'(\alpha)=\sqrt3 \cos\alpha -\sin\alpha$$
Thus $$f'(\alpha)=0\iff \sqrt3\cos\alpha=\sin\alpha\iff \sqrt3=\tan\alpha\iff \alpha=\frac{\pi}{3}$$ And since $f''(\alpha)=-\sqrt3\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha<0$ for $\alpha\in(0, \pi)$ $$f(\alpha)_{max}\text{ is achived for } \alpha\in(0, \pi)\text{ when } \alpha=\frac{\pi}{3}$$ Hence $$\sqrt3 \sin\alpha+\cos\alpha=f(\alpha)\leq\sqrt3 \sin\frac{\pi}{3}+\cos\frac{\pi}{3}=2$$

Therefore $$2bc\geq bc(\sqrt3 \sin\alpha+\cos\alpha)$$ And since the inequality $b^2+c^2\geq 2bc$ is almost trivial, we're done!

**Remark**

Observe that this proof uses the most basic trigonometry and calculus principles

Comment: I have not really check it, but sims a nice aproach.+1

Comment: As the best proof so far, it's the one that gets my upvote.

Comment: Actually one does not need calculus, since $$\cos\theta+\sqrt{3}\sin\theta=2\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}-\theta\right)\le 2$$

Answer (score 3):

using the Heron formula for $A$ we have $$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 4\sqrt{3}\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$ after squaring and rearanging we obtain
$$a^4+b^4+c^4\geq a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2$$ and this is true and follows from
$$x^2+y^2+z^2\geq xy+yz+zx$$

Comment: `after squaring and rearanging` I think you glossed over too summarily over that step. It's not obvious how that follows, and not everybody has a CAS at their fingertips to verify.

Comment: it is simple expanding and you will get what i wrote this is a proof by our math circle from Leipzig, the shortest one

Comment: why the $-1$ i don't see it?

Comment: My $-1$ is for the hand-waving. You make it look like that's a $1$-line proof, but omit the $1+$ pages of tedious calculations required to actually achieve that `squaring and rearanging`. The OP went to the pain of actually spelling out their $3$ proofs step by step. An answer that claims to compare (favourably) against those proofs should do the same.

Comment: i really don't understand your argumentations, it is simple Algebra only.

Comment: Your notion of "*simple*" must be different from mine. Yes, it may be plain algebra, and something that, say, Wolfram can do easily. Yet, that doesn't make it "*simple*" in my books. Sorry, guess we'll just have to agree to disagree on this point.

Comment: Are you a Dr at the university in Leipzig?

Comment: To be fair, expanding the terms in Heron's formula is really not a difficult step.  My only judgement is that it is not an interesting solution.  It is a bit over the top to downvote this solution, but who am I to complain?

Comment: @dxiv your definition of difficult is probably different... look at your top tags they are 5th grade math.

Comment: @AlecDiaz-Arias Point is that other answers, and the question itself, had far fewer blanks left to fill-in than this (otherwise workable) hint. That said, I am impressed that you found the time in your busy PhD schedule to grade my presence here and post such an insightful comment after a mere three months.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the first [Brocard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard_points) point of $\triangle ABC$ and $\varphi$ be the Brocard angle. Then, Ceva's theorem implies:
$$\sin^3\varphi = \sin(\alpha - \varphi)\sin(\beta-\varphi)\sin(\gamma-\varphi).$$ 
Now an immediate usage of the Jensen's inequality gives $\sin\varphi\leq\frac 12$ or equivalently:
$$\varphi\leq 30^\circ.$$
On the other hand, one can prove that $$\cot\varphi = \cot\alpha+\cot\beta+\cot\gamma = \dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{4S}\geq\sqrt{3}.$$

Another way is simply to state Finsler-Hadwiger inequality:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 4\sqrt{3}+(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2.$$