# Is the Weitzenbock inequality equivalent to the Roland inequality?

Tags: geometry

Is the Weitzenbock triangle inequality 
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq 4\sqrt{3}S$$
equivalent to the Roland inequality
$$ab + bc + ca \geq 4\sqrt{3}S?$$

Comment: Roland inequality is sharper, since $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ac$ holds by the rearrangement inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, Roland inequality is sharper since $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+ac+bc$ holds by the rearrangement inequality or simply from $(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2\geq 0$. About proofs, I have outlined some proofs of Weitzenbock inequality [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2278521/44121) (among them, a nice proof without words). The inequality

$$ ab+ac+bc \geq 4\Delta\sqrt{3} $$
can be proved by invoking Heron's formula, Ravi substitution and [Muirhead's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality), or simply by exploiting $ab=\frac{2\Delta}{\sin C}$ and the convexity of $\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$ over $(0,\pi)$.