# What are some nice proofs-by-cutting-and-pasting?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

I enjoy geometric proofs made by cutting-and-pasting. There are some famous examples for Pythagoras's Theorem. Here's another example for the Law of Cosines.

[image]

Do you know some other nice proofs using this method?

(***NOT*** for Pythagoras's Theorem, that's been done to death.)

I will add a bounty if someone shows me something particularly insightful.

Comment: Do not forget this proof of $25=26$: https://goo.gl/images/uWxBhK

Comment: I believe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2278521/44121) is another nice example.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my [trigonograph](http://trigonography.com/2017/10/22/the-law-of-cosines/) for the Law of Cosines, which involves cutting-and-*looking*:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An interesting proof of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac14\right)^n = \frac13$$

[image: image1]
We take a triangle with unit area an divide it into four parts of equal area. We do the same process with the upper triangle an repeat this till infinity!

[image: image2]
The area of each triangle is $$\left(\frac14\right)^n$$ where $n$ is the position of triangle from bottom.

[image: image3] 
Now we separate and rearrange the triangles:

[image: image4]
As the number and sizes of triangles are same, their areas will be equal. The area of the light shaded portion will be $$1/3$$

[image: image5]
$$\therefore \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac14\right)^n = \frac13$$

[image: image6]
**Source of the pictures-**  [Infinite Sums | Geometric Series | Explained Visually](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-y1Ob0K63hc)

You can follow his channel at [Think Twice](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9yt3wz-6j19RwD5m5f6HSg/search?query=geometric+series) for more such interesting visual proofs.

*PS* Another interesting cutting pasting proof is [Area of dodecagon | Beautiful geometry | Visual mathematics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQ4Kv6zdOe0)